# Passport isAuthenticated() always returns false?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

So I am having a problem with Passport I've been trying to move from my original method of authentication because Passport supports other types like Google and GitHub. I'm trying to implement the local authentication and it doesn't seem to be working, even after looking up many articles and they all don't work.

This is at the top of the code:

```js
const cookieExpirationDate = new Date();
cookieExpirationDate.setDate(cookieExpirationDate.getDate() + 7);

app.use(session({
    secret: secret_key,
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'strict',
        expires: cookieExpirationDate
    }
}));

// PASSPORT //
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({

        usernameField: 'username',

        passwordField: 'password',

        passReqToCallback: true //passback entire req to call back
    }, async function (req, username, password, done) {


        if (!username || !password) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Please complete the form!'})
        }
        const reqBody = {
            response: req.body['h-captcha-response'],
            secret: captcha_key
        }
        let axiosResult = await axios.post('https://hcaptcha.com/siteverify', qs.stringify(reqBody), {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
        if (axiosResult.data.success === true) {
            let results = await runQuery('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE (username = ? OR email = ?)', [username, username])
            const forwarded = req.headers['x-forwarded-for']
            const ip = forwarded ? forwarded.split(/, /)[0] : req.connection.remoteAddress

            if (!results.length) {
                let amtLeft = await loginAttempts(ip);
                if (amtLeft > 1) {
                    return done(null, false, {message: `Incorrect Username and/or Password! (${amtLeft} attempt(s) left)`});
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, {message: `You must wait 15 minutes before trying again!`});
                }
            }
            let user = results[0]
            let isMatch = await bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)
            if (!isMatch) {
                let amtLeft = await loginAttempts(ip);
                if (amtLeft > 1) {
                    return done(null, false, {message: `Incorrect Username and/or Password! (${amtLeft} attempt(s) left)`});
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, {message: `You must wait 15 minutes before trying again!`});
                }
            } else {
                if (user.activation_code === "activated") {
                    return done(null, user)
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Check your email for an activation email!'})
                }
            }
        } else {
            return done(null, false, {message: `You must complete the captcha!`});
        }
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async function (usrid, done) {
    let results = await runQuery('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = ?', usrid)
    done(results[0]);
});
```

Login API part:

```js
app.post('/login_sys', regularFunctions, function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', {failWithError: true}, function (error, user, info) {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(500).json(error);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json(info);
        }
        return res.status(200).send('Success')
    })(req, res, next);
})
```

regularFunctions:

```js
let regularFunctions = [
    bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}),
    bodyParser.json(),
    function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('Authenticated: ' + req.isAuthenticated())
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            req.session.loggedin = true;
            return next();
        } else {
            req.session.loggedin = false;
            return next();
        }
    }
]
```

I need it to return some sort of notification to the client if it fails or succeeds because I have a little pop up that lets them know they are getting redirected if it works and to notify them of their attempts left. The problem is it works and says that it logged in but when I refresh the page it never did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok just found out the answer after searching for a while, I had to use `req.login` inside the login_sys route.